# Simple find and replace xml header using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file with this header;

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
```

I want to replace the encoding value so it looks like this;

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-16'?>
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this using xsl version 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `<xsl:output encoding='utf-16' />` tag.

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_output.asp

As far as managing how it's input, that's up to the XML parser. The identity template with the extra `<xsl:output` element should be all you need.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="utf-16"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I see that this does not keep the indentation that existed in the xml before it was modified with the xsl. Is there a way of not messing up indentations and CRLFs?

Comment: Oh yeah, just add `indent="yes"` to the `<xsl:output` element. Strictly speaking though, that reformats it. If you really want to preserve it perfectly as is, then you need to have your XML parser preserve whitespace, and possibly add `<xsl:preserve-space elements="*" />` to the stylesheet.